# ! Missing } inserted.<inserted text>} \end{thebibliography}

Tags: errors

I continuously get this error. Even though there is nothing missing or extra in line 132. I also checked for similar errors but could not find proper solution that could work for me.

Error:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.132 \end{thebibliography}
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

Code snippet:

```
\begin{figure}[h] 
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{210}
\caption{{\small Schematic}}
\label{fig:210}                   % 132 line
\end{figure}
```

Comment: The error message says the problem is on a line that contains `\end{thebibliography}`. So possibly the problem is at (or somewhere before) line 132 of the `.bbl` file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Considering the `\end{bibliography}` part in the error, I suspect the line number refers to the `.bbl` file, not the `.tex` file.

Comment: This is the 132nd line in bib file. Is there any problem?

Comment: The line number refers to the `.bbl` file, not to the `.bib` file. Please strip down your tex- and your bib-file as long as it still shows the problem, and provide both files.

Comment: line 132 contains the text `\end{thebibliography}` so not the files you show but the bbl file, but it just means that you have an error earlier in one of your entries

Comment: I do not know how but it worked. I went to Tools->BibTex and then just tried again to run (quick build) and the process exited normally. Thank you everyone for your time and help. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because insufficient information was provided to diagnose the cause of the problem and because it appears to have been solved without providing further information as to how or why the remedy worked.